# Dot42 gives "object reference not set to an instance of an object" when inputting registration key

Tags: dot42

Dot42 gives "object reference not set to an instance of an object" when inputting registration key. Manual activation from the website is not working...

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB3MJ.jpg

[edit 1]
Currently using Windows 7

[edit 2]
Can someone please verify? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just a week, dot42 is an Open Source project. You can find it here:
https://github.com/dot42

From these sources you can build a version that does not require activation. In fact, the entire license mechanism has been removed. The version that you build from the sources corresponds to the Professional version.

Thanks for reminding that we should post a release to the web site that is build from the sources as posted on github.

Comment: Thank you Frank. Can you please explain a simple step by step on how to do that for others that don't know how to build from a source? Thanks again!